# Angular nested routes showing blank page

Tags: angular, nested-routes, router-outlet

I want to make the nested routes in angular. I want the customer to navigate into the shop and add products to the cart, when done adding products to the cart, proceed to checkout.
Below is my **app-routing-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { CartComponent } from './shop/cart/cart.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './shop/cart/checkout/checkout.component';
import { ShopComponent } from './shop/shop.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  {
    path: 'shop', 
    component: ShopComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'cart', component: CartComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutComponent},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  {path: '**', pathMatch:'full', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

When I navigate to the shop http://127.0.0.1:4200/shop it shows everything there but when I navigate to the cart http://127.0.0.1:4200/shop/cart or http://127.0.0.1:4200/shop/cart/checkout it shows blank page nothing is being rendered there. I tested the routes without nesting it works well, which means that the problem is in nested routes

**shop.component.html**

```
<div>
    <!--shop content here-->
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**cart.component.html**

```
<div>
    <!-- cart content here-->
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Please I need your help.

I inspected the page see what are there
[In Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYOcS.png)

Comment: seems to be fine, could you check the console for errors? if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Comment: @NarenMurali see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYOcS.png

Comment: please provide a basic stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Answer (score 1):

After googling, I found that in my index.html I was missing `<base href="/">`
Now it is working very well. this is the reference on [angular base tag](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag)